# HTML: <ul> tag laysover edge of div area

Tags: html, css

The li tag in the ul is not indented for some reason. is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 1 of your CSS file is the issue.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

With that declaration you are setting the margin and padding of your list item to 0; as a result it does not appear indented.

To solve the issue, you should include some default styles for your elements.  As an example, with my stylesheets the first line will be the CSS reset, followed by some generic styles for various elements.

```
/*CSS Reset*/
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
/*Generic Styles*/
ul{list-style:disc;margin:1em 0 1em 3em}
li{margin:.3em 0}
```

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW Look at my edit which shows a style you can add to fix the styling for your list item.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

you can do the same for specific elements

```
a, #header, #banner, #content, #bodyArea, #left, #nav, #img2, #img3,......
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

it's a lengthy collection of all your elements which has

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```